# Is "general feedback on game" on-topic?

Tags: support

I am working on an Android game scenario inspired by Moon Patrol. I am making progress and I don't have any very specific problems. I have posted the code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196658/improved-android-game-inspired-by-moon-patrol) and the beta version is available for beta test on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.android.buggy)

I want feedback but I don't know what to ask. Should I not ask because I don't really have a technical problem, I just want feedback in general from some specialist?

Comment: That is what [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for. General feedback on game are not *really* welcome here(there are exceptions) but in general if you want feedback you should go to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) or [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, open-ended "feedback" on just about *anything* -- game ideas, actual game products, intended mechanical or technical designs -- falls under either the category of "primarily opinion based" or the category of "too broad" and is thus off-topic here.

Questions that propose "this is how I'm going to solve , is this good/bad/any ideas?" fall into this category, but are generally easier to edit into something on-topic by rephrasing them as "how do I solve " and encouraging the asker to re-post their intended solution as an answer, submitting it to feedback and votes.

It doesn't seem possible to do this in a general way with "what do you think of my game" questions, so I think you're better off asking them elsewhere (either on SE as noted in some comments, or on another site altogether like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).